# How to make two Java objects from the same class behave differently

Tags: java, class, oop

I'm doing a simulator that has a class called service, which has a row of waiting clients as an attribute (which is an Arraylist). In the simulation there's only two services running, but they will have their own type of customer. At a point the service A can help service B, attending to B's customers. This is where the problem is: How can i make one service access B's row of customers while never allowing B to access A's?

Comment: How will A interact with B?  Will B call methods on A, or vice versa?  Will it be handled by dispatcher/3rd object?  There's not really enough information on how these objects are interacting to provide an implementation that will work.  Try posting some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `serviceType` state in your class. So whenever you create a service instance, you assign the `serviceType` based on the type of the service. So when one service is trying to attend another service's customer, you can check the `serviceType` and decide whether to allow him or not.

Answer (score 0):

What user Stinepike mentioned is one possibility. Depending on your implementation, if you want an "access control list" to control which instance can access to the current class' attribute, you can maintain a list:

```
public class Service{
    private ArrayList<Service> accessControl;
    private Customer customer;       

    public Service(){
        accessControl = new ArrayList<Service>();
    }

    public void grantAccessTo(Service s){
        accessControl.add(s);
    }

    public boolean hasAccess(Service s){
        accessControl.contains(s);
    }

    private Customer getCustomerByACL(Service s){
        if(hasAccess(s))
            return customer;
        else 
            //throw an exception or return null..
    }
}
```

Using the list:

```
Service a = new Service();
Service b = new Service();  //b cannot access a
b.grantAccessTo(a);         //a can access b
```